# Windows 7 BootDevice Not Found after failing to install linux

Tags: windows-7, bootloader

I have used ubuntu on my laptop for some months. A few days ago, the repository system or whatever it is called ran into problem. I can no longer install, update or upgrade my ubuntu system. After trying several times to fix it, I decided to move to another Minux distro, I tried to install Manjaro first, the installation is supposed to succeed as there is no sign of error, but when i reboot my system, it says :

> BootDevice Not Found
>
> Please install an operating system on your hard disk

So I thought I did something wrong in the installation process. I tried to reinstall manjaro several times, but no luck. Then I decided to try deepin , but I got the same problem, now i decided to give up on linux and just want to get my windows back, what should I do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install Windows 7 from a boot media. While installing, reformat the disk.

If you need to save data, use a Linux Live CD or USB to copy away the data
before starting.

I can't tell you where to find Windows 7 install media, so I hope you still have it.

Comment: is there no way to keep my windows system ?

Comment: I understand then that Windows still exists on the disk and that Linux was installed in dual boot. Try then to do [Startup Repair](https://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/681-startup-repair.html). If that doesn't work, let me know, as there are many more actions you can do.

Comment: when i click repair your computer, it gives me an error message : "this version of system recovery options is not compatible with the version of windows you are trying to repair".

Comment: The boot media must be of exactly the same version as the one installed. If you have Windows 7 SP1 on the disk, the boot media must also be of the same version.

Comment: it is fixed now, thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

I restored some time ago, a system MBR using testdisk utility see this [link](https://cstan.io/?p=8878&lang=en)
I hope this will help you.